# new to using foreach with an array and having problems

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach

I am trying to take an array that I have in a class and then use a foreach statement to iterate the values into a table.

my class is set up like the following:

```
public class items
{
   private string[] list;

   public items()
   {
      list[0] = "apples";
      list[1] = "oranges";
      list[2] = "grapes";
      list[3] = "bananas";
   }
}
```

In my `page_load` event  I am trying to call the class:

```
list fruit = new list();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.Append("<table id=\"items\">");
sb.Append("<tr>");
sb.Append("<th>Item</th>");
sb.Append("<th>Description</th>");
sb.Append("<th>Unit Cost</th>");

foreach(string fruit in list)
{
   sb.Append(String.Format("{0}", items.fruit));
}
```

I am new to using the `foreach` loops and its really confusing.  I am hoping for some clarity if I am on the right track.

Thanks.

Comment: hozdamn convert the values you are trying to assign in the list an convert it to a string[] then you can use extension method to convert that to a List or you can work directly with the Array

Comment: You'll need to be more specific -- what's "not working" that you expect to work? There's quite a bit wrong with your code for us to guess where the problem is.

Comment: if you want the value accessible change `private string[] list;` to `protected string[] list;`

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to build the markup for HTML table around the list of fruit, you should put the part that does the markup around each individual item into the loop as well:

```
 sb.Append("<table id=\"items\">");
 sb.Append("<tr>");
 sb.Append("<th>Item</th>");
 sb.Append("<th>Description</th>");
 sb.Append("<th>Unit Cost</th>");
 sb.Append("</tr>");
 foreach(var fruit in list) { // Use "var" or the exact type for the fruit
     sb.Append("<tr>");
     // I am assuming here that the fruit has Description and Cost.
     // You may need to replace these names with names of actual properties
     sb.Append(String.Format("<td>{0}</td>", fruit.Description));
     sb.Append(String.Format("<td>{0}</td>", fruit.Cost));
     sb.Append("</tr>");
 }
sb.Append("</table>");
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is this:

```
sb.Append("<table id=\"items\">");
sb.Append("<tr>");
sb.Append("<th>Item</th>");
sb.Append("<th>Description</th>");
sb.Append("<th>Unit Cost</th>"); 
sb.Append("</tr>");
foreach(string fruit in list)
{
   sb.Append("<tr>");
   sb.Append(String.Format("{0}", fruit));
   sb.Append("description");
   sb.Append(String.Format("2p");
   sb.Append("</tr>");
}
sb.Append("</table>");
```

Comment: Where are you building the HTML...?

Comment: I tried the above but I keep getting the message "The name list does not exist in the current context"

Comment: That's because of how you have List Defined Hozdaman.. look at the other comments / answers also why do you need a class for items where you are defining the ordinal values..? shy not just have a string[] defined with the values ..?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
foreach(string s in fruit)
{
    sb.Append(String.Format("{0}", s));
{
```

Comment: Where are you building the HTML...?

Comment: i am building the html through page_load using stringbuilders

Answer (score 0):

There's a few problems with your code.  First off, `items.list` is not accessible outside the `items` class, thus there's no way to iterate through it in your `page_load` event.  You'll have to make it accessible:

```
public class items
{
   private string[] list;

   public string[] List
   {
      get { return list; }
   }

   // ...
}
```

Now, you'll be able to instantiate your `items` class like you're doing on `page_load`:

```
items fruit = new items();
```

And loop through the `List` property of your `items` class:

```
foreach(string f in fruit.List)
{
   sb.Append(String.Format("{0}", f));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Linq`: Assuming your Array is fruit

```
fruit.ToList().ForEach(f=> sb.Append(String.Format("{0}", f));
```

Ideally if you had `description` and `unitCost` in your list, you could have add all `<tr>` tags to the table body like;

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<table id=\"items\">");
sb.Append("<tr><th>Item</th><th>Description</th><th>Unit Cost</th></tr>");

newList.ToList()
 .ForEach(f=> 
          sb.Append(String.Format("<tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td><td>{2}</td></tr>", 
                         f.item, f.desc, f.unitCost))
         );
sb.Append("</table>");
```

Comment: what about the `<Table>` and ending `</Table>` tags

Comment: @DJKRAZE; He already had `<table>` tag and ending `</table>` tag can be added after `ForEach()` like I have updated above.

Comment: I doubt the OP will understand Linq if he stated he doesn't understand foreach but nice answer Kaf

Comment: That's true.. I was thinking more in the terms of crawl before he walks in all due respect..